# MongoDb whether to retiain _id or not in case of unique profile name required in the document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Im using MongoDb for storing people profile .The profile name must be unique for every user . So can i use this unique name as _id field and replace the MongoDb generated ObjectId or is it a bad practice to replace it ?? What would a ideal solution in this case ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_id property is the unique primary key which is automatically indexes so as far as I know, we can't remove/replace it. However, we can make another field to be unique (same as _id) using Unique Index.

> A unique index causes MongoDB to reject all documents that contain a
>   duplicate value for the indexed field.

Source: [MongoDB Unique Index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique)

Here is an example:

*// Make profileName field in testUnique collection to be unique index*

```
db.testUnique.ensureIndex({"profileName":1},{unique:true})
```

*// Try to insert a document*

```
db.testUnique.insert({profileName:"use"},{text:"test"})
```

*//Try to insert another profileName with same value*

```
db.testUnique.insert({profileName:"use"},{text:"test"})
```

**Ouput error as duplication**

> WriteResult({     "nInserted" : 0,    "writeError" : {        "code" : 11000,
>         "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate
>   key error index: TestPlatform.testUnique.$profileName_1  dup key: { : \"1\"
>   }"    } })

Comment: If there is a natural unique key for a collection, this value can be provided as the `_id` instead of using the default ObjectId. The only obvious downside is that `_id`s are immutable, so renaming a profile (if the name was used for the `_id`) would involve copying the document to one with the new `_id` and deleting the original.